# Take Screenshot of a custom listclass

Tags: c#, custom-controls, screenshot

There is a program with a long list, from which I would like to take screen shots from. The Problem is, that there are only 14 of about 100 shown. How can I take a screen shot of the entire list?

The one approach that comes to my mind is basically send a PG-Down click to this list, take a new screen shot and merge them together. Are there any easier and quicker solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may grasp the concept from

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/IECapture.aspx &

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/windowsnapshot.aspx

and replace the window handle of IE by Custom listClass window